# kafka and zookeeper cannot connect - it is being refused

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kubernetes-pod

I am currently running kafka and the required zookeeper on a kubernetes cluster, but keeps getting connection errors when kafka tries to connect to zookeeper, which I can't seem to resolve.

Other pods within the cluster can reach it, but for some reason I am not able to reach it using Kafka`?

How come

Here is my kubernetes manifest which include the kafka and zookeeper setup and their services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: leader-zookeeper
spec:
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: client
  selector:
    app: leader-zookeeper
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2181
  - name: follower
    port: 2888
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2888
  - name: election
    port: 3888
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3888
  - name: admin-server
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  serviceName: zookeeper-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: "gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-zookeeper:1.0-3.4.10"
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "100Mi"
            cpu: "0.5"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: server
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: admin-server          
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - "start-zookeeper \
          --servers=1 \
          --data_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
          --data_log_dir=/var/lib/zookeeper/data/log \
          --conf_dir=/opt/zookeeper/conf \
          --client_port=2181 \
          --election_port=3888 \
          --server_port=2888 \
          --tick_time=2000 \
          --init_limit=10 \
          --sync_limit=5 \
          --heap=512M \
          --max_client_cnxns=200 \
          --snap_retain_count=3 \
          --purge_interval=12 \
          --max_session_timeout=60000 \
          --min_session_timeout=4000 \
          --log_level=DEBUG"
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - "zookeeper-ready 2181"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5     
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
        runAsUser: 1000
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: data
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-pdb
  name: zookeeper-pdb
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: broker
    port: 9092
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka
  name: kafka
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -exc
        - |
          unset KAFKA_PORT && \
          export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-} && \
          export KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://${POD_IP}:9092 && \
          exec /etc/confluent/docker/run
        env:
        - name: POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS
          value: -Xmx1G -Xms1G
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: leader-zookeeper:2181
        - name: KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
          value: /opt/kafka/data/logs
        - name: KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR
          value: "1"
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -ec
            - /usr/bin/jps | /bin/grep -q SupportedKafka
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        name: kafka-broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: kafka
          protocol: TCP
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/kafka/data
          name: datadir
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datadir
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-pdb
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  maxUnavailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
```

and here is the log from the kafka pod:

```
2019-12-18T22:59:44.6809224Z  [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=leader-zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@1ddc4ec2
2019-12-18T22:59:44.6980203Z  [main-SendThread(leader-zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server leader-zookeeper/10.104.189.16:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-18T22:59:45.8097553Z  [main-SendThread(leader-zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: leader-zookeeper/10.104.189.16:2181: Connection refused
2019-12-18T22:59:46.91975Z  [main-SendThread(leader-zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server leader-zookeeper/10.104.189.16:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2019-12-18T22:59:47.9634735Z  [main-SendThread(leader-zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket error occurred: leader-zookeeper/10.104.189.16:2181: Connection refused
2019-12-18T22:59:49.0653514Z  [main-SendThread(leader-zookeeper:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server leader-zookeeper/10.104.189.16:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

how do i connect them - as this is required?

Comment: I suggest you try this - https://strimzi.io/ or https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts